# Load Gdk Pixbuf from string

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtkmm, gdk

in my program I want to use an image file without it being present on the local hard drive.

So, I used `xxd -i` to generate an `unsigned char[]` containing the image data and embedded this in my program.

But now I am stuck trying to load a `Gdk::Pixbuf` (or a Gtk Image) from this, since I dont seem to find a function which could do that.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a job for [`Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Pixbuf.html#a8a3b524f26acd2f9efc4abe9c294d341).

Note that an array like that is *not* a string, which might explain why you had problems finding this.

It's in the ["Image Data in Memory"](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html) category which isn't that hidden, on the other hand.

*EDIT2*: Changed to the same function's gtkmm API wrapper, after comment.

Comment: Nice, thanks :) I was confused about all that "from memory" stuff since Im not really into how using binary data works and couldnt quite understand what the documentation was trying to tell me ^^ regards, tagelicht

Comment: By the way, the Gio::Resource (or GResource) system is made for exactly this. You just need to get the build magic correct. Here's an example where I do this for Glade UI files with gtkmm: https://github.com/murraycu/prefixsuffix/commit/fbe5f470ddbd3dffc044a0d216759fa8a6fe216d . In my Glom project, I do this for icon data too.

Comment: As the question was about Gdk::Pixbuf, rather than GdkPixbuf, this is the correct link to the gtkmm API: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Pixbuf.html#a8a3b524f26acd2f9efc4abe9c294d341

Comment: @murrayc Thanks, that's better. I tend to map all wrappers back to the plain C API since that's the one I'm most familiar with, but that's not very clear of course.